# Groovy - with closure with multiple references

Tags: grails, groovy

I'm trying to parse a JSON data and assign it to a POJO in Grails.

I started with

```
obj.param=jsonRequest.jsonWrap.attrib.something.jsonParam
```

After some experimenting and refactoring, it looks like this now.

```
jsonRequest.jsonWrap.attrib.something.with {
    obj.param1=jsonParam1
    obj.param2=jsonParam2
    //...
    }
  }
```

Now, can I avoid the repeated use of obj reference?

Comment: the two lines with `param1=...` are copy and paste errors?

Comment: Why `jsonRequest.with { jsonWrap.attrib.something.with {` instead of just `jsonRequest.jsonWrap.attrib.something.with {`?

Comment: @cfrick two lines were a typo. @BalRog `jsonRequest.jsonWrap.attrib.something.with {` is also fine. Edited the code.

Comment: Can't you just use [Data Binding](http://grails.org/doc/latest/guide/theWebLayer.html#dataBinding)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm imagining that your actual starting point is something like the following. On the JSON side:

```
import groovy.json.JsonSlurper

String jsonText = '''{
  "jsonWrap":{
    "attrib":{
      "something":{
        "jsonParam1": "value1",
        "jsonParam2": "value2",
        "jsonParam3": "value3",
        "jsonParam4": "value4",
        "jsonParam5": "value5"
      }
    }
  }
}'''

def jsonRequest = new JsonSlurper().parseText(jsonText)
```

On the Groovy side:

```
class ObjectType {
    def param1, param2, param3, param4, param5
}

def obj = new ObjectType()
```

Now, if I had any control over how either the JSON side or the Groovy side are defined then I would do my darnedest to ensure that the property names of the JSON "something" object are exactly the same as the property names in the Groovy "ObjectType" class. For example, like this:

```
class ObjectType {
    def jsonParam1, jsonParam2, jsonParam3, jsonParam4, jsonParam5
}
```

Then, unmarshalling the "something" object into Groovy is as simple as this:

```
def obj = new ObjectType(jsonRequest.jsonWrap.attrib.something)
```

Only one reference to the JSON object. Only one reference to the Groovy object. And the former is used to instantiate the latter. And furthermore, notice that there is no need to reference the properties at all. That is, JSON objects from the slurper are instances of Map, so if the property names match up, you can use the default "Map constructor" syntax.

---

If, however, you do not control property naming in either set of objects, I would still recommend a different Map-based short-cut. First define a constant Map from one set of property names to the other, like so:

```
def map = [param1:"jsonParam1", param2:"jsonParam2", param3:"jsonParam3",
           param4:"jsonParam4", param5:"jsonParam5"]
```

Then I would use something like this for the object unmarshalling:

```
def obj = new ObjectType().with { o ->
    jsonRequest.jsonWrap.attrib.something.with { j ->
        map.each { oParam, jParam -> o[oParam] = j[jParam] }
    }
    o
}
```

Answer (score 2):

i don't think there is a trivial way to trick groovy into "use objectA, if getting is needed and objectB for setting". If `obj` above is a map or you can apply a map to this object, then you could produce a map in your `with` block and use this.  If you have to have nested structures then more work is needed.

```
def jsonParam = new Expando([ p1: 'p1', p2: 'p2', p3: 'p3', ])

def obj = new Expando(
    jsonParam.with{
        [
        param1: p1,
        param3: p3,
        ] // `with` will return this map
    })

assert obj.param1==jsonParam.p1
assert obj.param3==jsonParam.p3
```

I use expandos for simple code.